# In how many different ways can you arrange 42 identical balls into 10 different boxes...

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can you arrange 42 identical balls into 10 different boxes so that any two different boxes have a different number of balls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done... Unless multiple empty boxes count as a "different number of balls."

If you leave the first box empty, put one ball in the second box, and fill each consecutive box minimally such that is has a different number of boxes than its predecessor, 9 balls go in the 10th box.  That makes for 45 balls, which is 3 more than you have.